# Calculate the mean, the median and the quartiles.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $D=\{(x,y):x>0,x^2+y^2<1\}$ and let $(X,Y)$ be the random variable with the density:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{2}{\pi}1_{D}(x,y).$$
Let $Z=\frac{Y}{X}$.
Calculate the mean, the median and the first and third quartiles of $Z$.

Comment: I can see an instruction, but what in particular is your question? The median should be obvious, as should the mean if there is one.

Comment: Thank you Henry, of course your comment is a hint for me, so I will try to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we fix $Z=z$, this implies the linear relationship: $y=zx$, so we can see $Z$ as a random slope of a line through the origin. In fact, each $z$ simply specifies a rotated diameter of the unit circle. Thus, we can re-parametrize this in terms of a random angle:

$$\theta \sim U\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

However, the slope will certainly not have a uniform distribution, since $Z \in (-\infty,\infty)$

The slope ($Z$) associated with a particular $\theta$ is $Z=\tan(\theta)$; therefore,

$$\tan^{-1}(Z)=\theta\sim U\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$$

But, this implies that $\frac{\tan^{-1}(Z)}{\pi}+0.5=\frac{\theta}{\pi}+0.5\sim U[0,1] \implies \frac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{\pi}+0.5$ is the quantile function, and $f_Z(z)=\frac{d}{dz}F_Z = \frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)}$...This is a standard cauchy distribution....what does this density tell you about the mean?

Comment: I think you may have taken the derivative of $\dfrac{\tan(z)}{\pi}+0.5$ rather than $\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(z)}{\pi}+0.5$

Comment: @Henry...oops, lol...yep. Ill fix it.

Comment: @Henry there we go...now the answer is very obvious!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and comments. I will only add the calculation for the distribution of $Z$. I will use polar coordinates. For $t\in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ we have: $F_Z (t)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{x^2+y^2<1,x>0,y<tx}dx\,dy=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{r<1,\tan \alpha<t} r\,dr\,d\alpha=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\tan^{-1} (t)}{\pi}$. Hence $Z$ has the Cauchy distribution and has no mean. The median is 0 as $F(t)=\frac{1}{2} \iff t=0$ and the quartiles are equal to $-1$ and $1$ as $F(-1)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $F(1)=\frac{3}{4}$.

Comment: @Almostsure yep, nice job. Good luck with your studies!